# consumo webservice rest retorna: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-service, java-ee, rest

Prazados,

Estou com um problema para consumir um Webservice de terceiros, ao tentar conssumir o mesmo pelo java script o retorno q recebo é:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://xxxxxxxxx:yyyyy/sccwebclient/svc/filetransfers/?startedDay%3E2018-05-02T00%3A00%3A00.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

porem ao tentar consumir o mesmo pelo postman eu consigo obter a resposta desejada, que um Json, para consumir o mesmo é necessário passar no cabecario um login e senha, da seguinte forma:

> Authorization: xxxx

para consumir o webservise eu criei o seguinte script:

```
function getListaWebService(url){
                $.ajax({
                    'url': url,
                    Type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "xxxx " + geraBase64("xxxx", "yyyy")
                    }
                }).done(function (objJson){
                    console.log("objJson", objJson);
                }).error(function (err) {
                    console.log("err", err);
                }); }
```

o que eu fiz de errado, se for problema de cross domain, como eu posso resolver por JS ou java?

Comment: Isso é porque está a trabalhar localmente (localhost) para contornar isso veja esta página https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Comment: Não tem problema ser localhost ou não, tem que saber se no servidor determinada requisição espera algo. OPTIONS por exemplo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo,bom dia Tente habilitar o ;CORS no seu WebService no caso em c#, que é a linguagem q uso fica assim no metodo do WS:

```js
[HttpGet]
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public IEnumerable < string > Get() {
  return new string[] {
    "value1",
    "value2"
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recentemente eu andei tendo o mesmo problema e tive que estudar um pouco do CORS:

- Access-Control-Max-Age -> tempo máximo que ele fica cacheado no
  navegador.
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin -> Especifica quem tem acesso ao
  determinado recurso.
- Access-Control-Allow-Credential -> Verifica as credenciais de acesso
  como cookies.
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods -> Especifica quais metodos são
  permitidos
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers -> Ele compara e valida o cabeçalho
  durante a requisição

Você precisa verificar se o servidor espera algum tipo de informação na requisição.

No meu caso precisava mandar um **OPTIONS**.